# Row spanning in Bootstrap Grid design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Grid layout in Bootstrap.

How do I make a particular control(say text area) span for 3 rows in this grid design?

Is it possible with Grid layout?

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you've tried ? Or are you looking for an existing code ?

Comment: You could certainly do that. What you would want to do is use nested columns.

Here is Bootstrap's nested columns material:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

You would just need to specify the height of the control so that it matched the height of the 3 input boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to use a nested grid or a form group.

First, split the page into two columns, the left with more than one row and the right with only one row. In the provided example, I demonstrate how you could use a form group in the left column to get the labels/inputs exactly as in your diagram.

```
<div class="row">

  <!-- Left Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Input 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Input 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Input 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Right Column -->
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>

</div>
```

### [See this working Plnkr example](http://embed.plnkr.co/5DM5kWgqaPoW2aFSPrV5/preview)

- Note that the plnkr needs to be wide enough to not apply the responsive layout and stack

If instead you wanted to use a nested grid to get the same effect, you would just define a new grid with rows/columns inside the left column.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make the textarea height align with the bottom of the third text box?

Comment: The short answer is that there isn't an easy way to do it. The longer answer involves using CSS to explicitly set the height of the rows and the text area so that they align. The issue is that bootstrap puts in margin/padding around elements so you would have to do some work to either explicitly set the heights of the rows on the left and the text area on the right so that they line up, or use javascript to inspect and modify the heights to make them align.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this, but try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

This uses the nested columns, like  @user3711852 suggested.